# Footer disappear when resizing

Tags: html, css

I try to make a responsive design but when I resizing its getting messy.. My css code is until line 15 the other is the menu css [Click here for code](http://jsfiddle.net/kac8p/3/)

So my code is only:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
}

main {
    margin:0;
    height: 85%;
}

body > footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#dedede
}
```

Comment: Can you please define "messy", we need to understand what is happening before we can fix it.

Comment: My title define the "messy", I mean footer disappear its not resizing

Comment: I dont want navigation bar to appear, i want it to resize to whatever screen size is

Comment: Do you mean that when you (the user) resize your browser window, the footer disappears?

Comment: I'm looking at the jsfiddle and playing around with the size and the footer never disappears, it jumps around; but never disappears.

Comment: You might want a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)? All I've noticed is that you can scroll far below the footer if the window is small; this would solve that.

Comment: When I say disappear I dont mean literally, its just go below and I need to scroll down to see it. I want to see my page at 100% width and height of the browser size.

Comment: So you want your footer to stay at the bottom of your screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/kac8p/6/. I cleaned up your footer code a little (you can leave that there though). I made the footer a class and wrapped it in a `<div>`. Then, I gave the footer a margin on the top. This makes it so the footer doesn't "mess up" when resized. Go ahead and look at the full size fiddle and resize your browser to see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/kac8p/6/embedded/result/

**EDIT:** I have a solution for what you want. This fiddle shows the footer all the way at the bottom of the screen, below the browser's scroll. I utilized things like width, height, and clear for this CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/kac8p/13/embedded/result/

Comment: But footer is not on bottom, its on middle

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle with the solution. It sets `margin: auto;`. This allows the footer to be automatically pushed down based on the amount of content. It still is responsive though. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/kac8p/7/embedded/result/

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed but I think its even better from what I tried to do

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you make some headway. If I understand, you want the footer all the way at the bottom. Let me see if I can make something like this. I will let you know of the results.